# Uses the User.Identity.Name as role

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I do not use of membership. I want to uses the User.Identity.Name  as role.

I have a table in sql:
**tblA**:

```
 id    username   password   role
 1     a          a2         admin  
 1     b          b2         user
```

**in login page:**

i add  characters to first  of User.Identity.Name as role.  i have two role:
if role is user : **"U-"**+ username
if role is admin : **"A-"**+ username

then use this as  User.Identity.Name

```
//....  
//if user is authenticated
//{
   string RoleAndUsername = user.role == "admin" ? "A-"+user.username : "U-"+user.username;
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RoleAndUsername, false);
//}
//...
```

in admin pages:

```
if (User.Identity.Name.Substring(0, 2) == "A-")
{
   //welcoe admin
}
else
{
   //access denied
}
```

Is safe this idea  to use role manager?

Thanks.

Comment: I would at least write a class that parses the values. So you make it `DRY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

I use the [Role-Provider Implementation into LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727173/how-to-role-provider-implementation-into-linq)

this Implementation uses from entity framework 6.0

Answer (score 1):

> Is safe this idea to use role manager?

It could be made safe, but it isn't very obvious for developers that need to maintain it.

Also, every time a new role is needed you'll have to change code, not just configuration - more maintenance problems...

I wouldn't recommend this idea... What value does `User.Identity.Name` have for anonymous users?